# Noise on PCB trace influences NTC measurement

Tags: pcb-design, rf, frequency, thermistor, ground-plane

I have a general question regarding noise in PCB-Designs.

The PCB I'm currently working on is failing some tests on the RF side. I have scanned the internet for information, but there are no concrete answers to noise reduction with this scenario.

Pictures of connection:

The NTC line is about 145 mm long.

[image: NTC trace to analog pin on MCU]

[image: This goes from MCU to end of board. About 143mm]

[image: NTC and resistor]

A test was done with different frequency signals (270 MHz - 310 MHz) and the NTC measurement showed big deviations.
I assume the problem is the length of the trace, but the length is needed.
How can I reduce the noise on it without disturbing the given NTC values?

I'm new to PCB designs so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where does the NTC thermistor connect (show us the schematic of that portion of the circuit)? What is the nominal resistance of the thermistor and the series resistor?

Comment: Low pass filter?

Comment: It connect directly to microcontroller and VCC (3.3V). NTC is 10k and resistor is aslo 10k.

Comment: Im thinking RC low pass filter, but can that be done without influencing the 10k NTC values?

Comment: Don't route it on the top layer/ the same layer as the RF parts? Also you need to be sure if this is a radiated problem or a conducted problem (like crosstalk). There might also be overall RF design problems, which is what I would suspect before anything else.

Comment: It is a two layer card @Lundin so there is limited space. As winny said, a low pass filter around the frequency 300 KHz will proabably work. But in the even higher range (around 500 KHz) will the signal then stagnate and not work?

Comment: @Ben If there are RF parts present on the board, you should not use 2 layers, simple as that. You will get EMC problems for barely anything gained. 4 layer PCBs are nearly as cheap as 2 layer ones these days.

Comment: Okay @Lundin. I will check this out. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pc trace for the ntc is a good antenna.Make it a poor antenna by filtering it with resistors and capacitors and possibly ferrite bead   low q inductors that look like resistors and do not ring .You have your fail frequencies to guide you to sensible component values which are small and cheap .You alternately could use outer pcb layers to enclose the noisey track to stop it picking up noise.